# Marker click event on react native maps not working in react ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, reactjs, react-native, google-maps-markers

I have tried by calling onPress method in MapView.Marker Tab, but its not working.

**This method for tracking marker click:**

```
markerClick(){
      console.log("Marker was clicked");
 }
```

> In render method, Map components are declared to display map and
>   markers on map. In onPress method I have called my custom method
>   markerClicked(). Still I am not getting the result.

```
render() {
        return (

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView style={styles.map}
              initialRegion={{
                  latitude: 37.78825,
                  longitude: -122.4324,
                  latitudeDelta: 0.0,
                  longitudeDelta: 0.0,
              }}
            >
            {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
              <MapView.Marker
                coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                title={marker.title}
                description={marker.description}
                onPress={() => this.markerClick()}
              />
            ))}
          </MapView>
        </View>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to add `<MapView.Callout>` in `<MapView.Marker>` tag.
Custom callout- you can customize marker info click window as your requirement.

I have used `TouchableHighlight` for `marker info window click`, so that you can able to redirect user to other screen on click of `custom callout`.

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                  <MapView style={styles.map}
                          initialRegion={{
                              latitude: 37.78825,
                              longitude: -122.4324,
                              latitudeDelta: 0.0,
                              longitudeDelta: 0.0,
                            }}>
                            {this.state.markers.map((marker) => (
                              <MapView.Marker
                                coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                                title={marker.title}
                                description={marker.description}>
                                  <MapView.Callout tooltip style={styles.customView}>
                                      <TouchableHighlight onPress= {()=>this.markerClick()} underlayColor='#dddddd'>
                                          <View style={styles.calloutText}>
                                              <Text>{marker.title}{"\n"}{marker.description}</Text>
                                          </View>
                                      </TouchableHighlight>
                                    </MapView.Callout>
                                </MapView.Marker>
                            ))}
                     </MapView>
                  </View>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working when I have added `<MapView.Callout>` in Map marker view.

Comment: I put  onPress on MapView.Callout and it works fine.

Answer (score 11):

To add to Anil's answer, you can use the 'onCalloutPress' callback on Marker to handle the callout press event, so that you don't need a TouchableHighlight in the callout:

```
<MapView.Marker
   coordinate={marker.coordinate}
   title={marker.title}
   description={marker.description}
   onCalloutPress={this.markerClick}>
   <MapView.Callout tooltip style={styles.customView}>
       <View style={styles.calloutText}>
          <Text>{marker.title}{"\n"}{marker.description}</Text>
       </View>
   </MapView.Callout>
</MapView.Marker>
```

Comment: what if we have 2 buttons inside 1 `Callout`?

Comment: @TomSawyer did you manage to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 5):

Try to add a "key" in your marker:

```
{this.state.markers.map((marker, i) => (
    <MapView.Marker
      key={i}
      coordinate={marker.coordinate}
      title={marker.title}
      description={marker.description}
      onPress={() => this.markerClick()}
    />
 ))}
```

Just use 'i' for testing, you should use an unique id

Comment: This is not working for me. I have used same code as you have mentioned above.

Comment: Do you have any another **solution** related **Marker click** in react native ios.
I have added `key={i}` element in `<MapView.Marker/>` component but still no marker clicked is working.

Comment: `i` is a unique id... also key has to be a string. `i` is an integer/number. You need to do `'' + i`

Comment: Very Good Answer this was to be accepted. Because Accepted answer is not working

Comment: same goes for me this answer works and I don't know why both of the above ones doesnot. Giving an upvote for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

onCalloutPress={this.markerClick()} worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
<MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinate}
    title={marker.title}
    description={marker.description}
    onPress={e => this.onPressMarker(e,index)}
>
```