# TouchableOpacity onLongPress not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps, long-press, touchableopacity

i have been trying to use a `TouchableOpacity` inside a `react-native-maps` `Marker` heres the code:

```
<MapView.Marker
     coordinate={{
     latitude: marker.lat,
     longitude: marker.lng
     }}
     anchor={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
     centerOffset={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
     calloutOffset={{ x: 0, y: 0}}
     title={marker.title}
     description="Sample Description"
                >
<TouchableOpacity
     onLongPress={() => {console.log("MARKER LONG PRESSED")}}
     delayLongPress={1000}
     onPress={()=>{console.log("MARKER PRESSED")}}
>
     // here i have a custom image for the marker
</TouchableOpacity>
</MapView.Marker>
```

now the problem is this works fine on ios both the `onPress` and `onLongPress` events get invoked but on android none of them gets called this is so confusing and i dont know why. is there something i am missing here or something i should be adding?

and also i am importing `ToucahbleOpacity` from `react-native-gesture-handler`. i tried importing it from `react-native` but that just doesnt work on both platforms

Answer (score 0):

android will have limitations here. Android renders the markers and the callout as bitmaps directly, and they don't have interactivity. So as far as I know you you can not

use long press functionality inside marker all you can use is onPress functionality which can be called inside marker component

```
<Marker onPress={() => {console.log('in')}}>
  <View>
    <TextWithStyle style={styles.markerText}>{'Home'}</TextWithStyle>               
  </View>
</Marker>
```

Or if this is not helpful. Checkout this answere if that helps
[Marker click event on react native maps not working in react ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654594/marker-click-event-on-react-native-maps-not-working-in-react-ios)